# clearColorFilter() don't work on android 2.3

Tags: android, android-layout

i'm using setColorFilter to color some button... the code is this:

```
    final Button falso = (Button) findViewById(R.id.falso);
    final Button vero = (Button) findViewById(R.id.vero);


    vero.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
        public void onClick(View v) {
            vero.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0x00000000, 0x00FF0FF));    
            falso.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            esame.set("V");
        }
    });


    falso.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
        public void onClick(View v) {
            falso.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0x00000000, 0x00FF0FF));
            vero.getBackground().clearColorFilter(); 
            esame.set("F");
        }
    });
```

when i click the button "vero" i want reset the colour of "falso" and viceversa.
i tried this code on android ics and all work good, but when i tried it on android 2.3 i have a bad surprise.

when i click the button the colour don't reset and i don't understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i find the solution:

```
use button.invalidate();
```

after i clear background

Answer (score 0):

Setting the ColorFilter to 0 will do thee job by clearing the filter.

```
vero.setInt(vero.getBackground(), "setColorFilter", 0);
```